# firstChild で取得した子要素の innerHTML が undefined になっている

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

ボタンを押下後、エレメントの最初の子要素を取得し、その要素の内容(例：a)をダイアログで表示したいのですが、undefinedと表示されます。どう修正すればよろしいでしょうか。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>あいうえお商店</title>

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="childcatch">
      <span>a</span>
      <span>b</span>
      <span>c</span>
      <span>d</span>
      <span>e</span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function findElement() {
        var element = document.getElementById("childcatch");
        var child = element.firstChild;
        alert(child.innerHTML);
      }
    </script>
    <button onclick="findElement()">最初の子を取得</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 6):

結論から言えば、`firstChild`ではなく`firstElementChild`にすれば解決します。

`firstChild`はElementに限定せずノードを返します。`<div id="childcatch">`と`<span>a</span>`の間に改行と空白があるため、そこにtext nodeが作成され、`firstChild`となります。そしてtext nodeは`innerHTML`プロパティを持たないので、`undefined`が返ってきたということです。

Answer (score 1):

[html5](/questions/tagged/html5)が付けられているので別のアプローチとして、[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)を使用することで、`document.getElementById()`よりも効率よく検索をすることができます。

> エレメントの最初の子要素を取得

をCSSセレクターで表現すると`#childcatch > *:first-child`とできますので

```js
function findElement() {
    var child = document.querySelector("#childcatch > *:first-child");
    alert(child.innerHTML);
}
```

と書けます。（DOMはNodeを対象とするため`firstChild`では意図しない結果となりますが、CSS Selectorは主にElementを対象とするため`:first-child`で問題ありません。）